# R changepoint, different number of outputs

Tags: r, time-series, change-point

I tried detect change points in R. I've ran following MWE in R.

```
library(changepoint)

mydata = c(2000, 2100, 2400, 2000, 4500, 4000, 10000, 12000, 11000, 10000 ,10500, 12000, 10000, 5000, 4000, 4500, 5100, 3800, 4100, 4500)

cpoints=cpt.mean(mydata, penalty='Manual', pen.value='100000000*diffparam', method="PELT", class=TRUE)

plot(cpoints,cpt.width=3,cpt.col='red')

cpts(cpoints)
param.est(cpoints)
```

Result is following:

[image]

I am expecting 3 changepoints (same in graph). 
However, cpts(cpoints) returns only two detected change points.
On the other hand, param.est(cpoints) returns three results.
Am I missing something?

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. However, the question is... How to retrieve the beginning of first stage/the first red line. 'The red line' does not always starts by the first element.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. The changepoints mark the point where the series changes (this is also obvious by eyeballing your data). By the way, please do not use answers for commenting, comments are meant for this.

Answer (score 4):

Changepoints mark where your time-series changes. In this case you observed two *changes* around time 6 (mean increased) and 14 (mean decreased).

Answer (score 0):

i took your "challenge match" 20 observations into AUTOBOX , a piece of software that i have helped to develop. It forms both the arima portion ( (0,0,0) in this case) and newly found intervention series (in this case 4) ... two level shifts and 2 pulses .

Here is the Actual/Fit and Forecast graph [image] and the equation [image] with model residuals here [image]

The Actual/Cleansed graph is here [image]

Note that the detection of two level shifts implies three regimes (local means)

I have been somewhat fixated on these kinds of problems. Particulaly when "large pulses or seasonal pulses create obfuscation" OR when an arima process is in play obfuscating simple identification OR when the actual baseline is a trending process. Simple tools work well when "things are simple" but often fail miserably when things are not as simple as your example. Before using any tool (free or otherwise) I would test it on a variety of cases ... some real some simulated/fabricated to measure/evaluate how robust the solution is.